# Trigger .click() on ajax element via another element (not another "click not working after ajax")

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using the little subscribe btn generated by campaignmonitor, and I want to trigger a click on that using $("button").click(); like this

```
$(document).on("click", ".trigger-cm", function(){
   $("button").click();
});
```

Obviously that doesn't work since "button" was loaded after the the fact, so how can i access it with jquery?

Comment: That's fine, as long as the button element exists when you click `.trigger-cm`.  Can you show us the markup of the button you are clicking and the button you want to click?

Answer (score 0):

Two of many ways

1. Load the button before and make it visible when ajax call is incoming.
2. Add your button when Ajax call is incoming like:

   var btn = $('button>Text.... /button>'); //generate button

   btn.click(function(){ ... }); //Set listener

   $("body").append(btn); //Add button to page or element